# Does Eth have an equivalent to Geth's --fast flag?

Tags: blockchain, cpp-ethereum

In a [previous question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/what-is-geths-fast-sync-and-why-is-it-faster), I asked how Geth's `--fast` flag worked. I'm now moving over to using Eth, so my question is: is there an equivalent option to allow Eth to quickly sync the block data? If so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The c++ implementation does not yet have the fast-sync feature. It can be used to fast sync *from*, but it will not fast sync itself.

You can track the progress on implementing this feature on [github](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/issues/177).