# Mist is synchronizing extremely slowly on Linux Ubuntu 15.10. Any way to speed it up?

Tags: mist

Mist is synchronizing extremely slowly on Linux Ubuntu 15.10. Any way to speed it up?

Current info:

> Downloading block 1,081,182 of 1,521,138.

It's downloading like a few blocks per minute, tops at the moment. So I suppose I have to wait for maybe 50-500 weeks or so if the speed does not increase somehow.

Any particular reason why it's so slow? 
Any way to speed it up?

Comment: Related http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4293/is-there-a-quicker-way-then-geth-fast-to-download-the-ethereum-blockchain

Answer (score 2):

If you have just installed your node (e.g. you aren't actively mining on it yet, and you don't care about saving any work you may have done), then you can reset geth and do a "fast sync", which will sync the entire blockchain in 20 minutes or less.

See here for more info:

[What is Geth's "fast" sync, and why is it faster?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/what-is-geths-fast-sync-and-why-is-it-faster)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to resolve it by deleting the DAO contract...basically, by stop watching it.  This happened to me on Mist version 7.2

Here's a link to DAOhub that also addresses the issue on Linux:

https://forum.daohub.org/t/ethereum-mist-not-updating/1807

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is before even starting up Mist for the first time.