# Deploying a smart contract from hosted wallet or light client

Tags: contract-deployment

At the moment I use the official Ethereum wallet / mist for deploying a contract to the Ethereum network.

Is there any other options for doing this either via different software clients or websites?

The reason I ask is that the Ethereum blockchain is becoming to large for my C: drive and the official Ethereum wallet / mist is hardwired to the C: drive (for the users) so I am unable to move it to a different drive.

Comment: Are you uploading to the livenet without testing or running on your own private chain?

Comment: I deleted the Ethereum blockchain database and run the following command : geth --fast.  This downloads a much smaller blockchain database and also works in unison with the official mist wallet.

Comment: You will still end up with the full blockchain - so although this gives you a fast start, it's not the answer you are looking for. My question was more about your approach to smart contract development. You can use Mist and your own blockchain to do your development on first, and it will work offline too.

Comment: You are incorrect about that.  Use the geth --fast parameter gives you a much smaller blockchain.

Comment: Arguably this is not _the_ blockchain, but only the receipts, with the loss of security that this implies by not having the full blockchain. Additionally you have to perform the whole task again each time you want to sync, unless you decide not to disconnect, but there are so many more issues with your approach. We have learnt from the DAO experience that security and contracts need to be carefully thought out.

Comment: I disagree, this is the "recent" blockchain and it is perfectly secure otherwise there would not be the option for it. It just depends on what you are planning to do with the blockchain. The DAO experience has nothing to do with this issue and so you are just confusing the subject at hand.

Comment: Before making such assertions please thoroughly read http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/what-is-geths-fast-sync-and-why-is-it-faster

Comment: Thanks but I have already seen that post. I used geth removedb before using geth --fast so everything is secure.