# ~/.ethereum takes a lot of disk space. What can I clean up without having to sync from scratch?

Tags: synchronization, cpp-ethereum

I am using cpp-eth on freebsd 10.3 with SSD and `~/.etherium` takes about 41 Gb of disk space:

```
~/.ethereum # du -sh *
    4.0K    config.rlp
    41G     d4e56740
    0b      geth.ipc
    4.0K    keys.info
    4.0K    keys.info.salt
    16K     network.rlp

~/.ethereum/d4e56740 # du -sh *
    39G     12041
    2.8G    blocks

~/.ethereum/d4e56740/12041 # du -sh *
    6.9G    extras
    32G     state
```

Is there anything in these folders that I could remove without having to sync all over again? This is my first sync and I am still about 100 000 blocks short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you had to use --fast and --cach check [What is Geth's "fast" sync, and why is it faster?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/what-is-geths-fast-sync-and-why-is-it-faster)

> NOTE: --fast can only be run if you are syncing your blockchain from
>   scratch and only the first time you download the blockchain for
>   security reasons..

you couldn't clean anything from the .ethereum folder you have to free some space from outside.

update : you could move the folder to another free location and run your client using the new directory path

Comment: I thought that there is no --fast option for cpp-eth, or am I mistaken?

Comment: sorry i thought you were using geth

Comment: I accept the updated suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

For the next one stumbling upon my problem. This is how I solved it using Bellaj's suggestion:

I used rsync to move the .ethereum folder to my HDD which had plenty of space for the blockchain. Then I started the cpp-eth with the following command:

```
# eth --db-path /hdd/path/to/my/blockchain/.ethereum
```

Then I pointed out the new location for ethconsole:

```
# ethconsole /hdd/path/to/my/blockchain/.ethereum/geth.ipc
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a symbolic link for `~/.ethereum/geth/chaindata`. But you can do the same for wherever your client is storing the blockchain.

Just create a matching directory structure on your other disk e.g. `mkdir -p /mnt/e/.ethereum/geth/chaindata`.

Move everything from the current directory and delete the old directory.
`mv ~/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/* /mnt/e/.ethereum/geth/chaindata; rmdir ~/.ethereum/geth/chaindata`.

Then create your symbolic link e.g. `ln -s 
/mnt/e/.ethereum/geth/chaindata ~/.ethereum/geth/chaindata`. And start up the client again.