# Concept of Geth Light Client for Mobile

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients

Need to understand how the Geth's light client parameter works. I want to understand the algorithm. Whether some part of the blockchain will be downloaded or will not download anything. In both cases what is the logic applied.

how is it different to the fast parameter of the geth client.

I specifically want to know about --light parameter. What exact algorithm is it using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Geth's "fast" sync, and why is it faster?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/what-is-geths-fast-sync-and-why-is-it-faster)

Comment: I am asking about Geth light parameter i.e. --light instead of --fast. So the question is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general background is described here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol

Comment: Usually link only answers are not welcomed.

Comment: Fair enough. But the question is very vague, I'm not sure what I could add that would be more helpful...

Comment: You an opt to close this question since it falls into **too broad** 
`Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.`