# Ethereum wallet

Tags: wallets, synchronization

Like many others I'm really struggling with setting up the ethereum wallet.
I deleted the chaindata folder in order to make the download process quicker. Unfortunately I closed the ethereum wallet during the downloading process because it had stopped (wanted to try if it still works with a VPN – it didn't). So I restarted the ethereum wallet and as u can see it restars from 0!? WTF? Is this normal?

[image]

Also I noticed there is no chaindata folder anymore even when I delete the ethereum wallet app and install it again … Is that normal?

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe [fast sync](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1161/5113) could help?

Answer (score 1):

The wallet app will take several days to download the chain data initially at this point. The Ethereum chain is very large.

I found running the gest.exe process from a command line more helpful as it would occasionally error out and the Wallet app did not provide any messaging to this effect.

You will want to start gest.exe from the command line (Search your system for this executable)

Then once it has starting syncing with peers open the Wallet application if you would like the progress information provided in the GUI.

On slower machines\connections it is probably not worth it at this point to run the Ethereum Wallet application if you are not able to sync after more than just a few days. You can always choose a cloud wallet like Coinbase or MyEtherWallet.

Comment: I would disagree with Coinbase being a cloud wallet, or wallet at all.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori why?

Comment: mmm because it a regulated exchange ?

Comment: *"A cryptocurrency wallet is a secure digital wallet used to store, send, and receive digital currency"* but by definition, it is a wallet. It just happens to be on a regulated exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Ethereum wallet client has old settings and doesn't download the latest version of geth. When that happens you can get sync issues like the above.

The best way to fix is to:

1. Download the latest version of Geth from https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/
2. In your C:\Users\****user****\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum folder - delete or rename the "geth" and "nodes" directories (be careful not to delete the keystore directory unless you have backed up your wallet)
3. Start geth on the command line - typically C:\Program Files\Geth\geth.exe - no need for additional options as the newer versions default to a fast sync. Leave it for a few hours (or a day or two on a platter drive) until its synced.
4. Close geth from the command line
5. Delete the files in your Ethereum wallet folder (typically C:\Users\****user****\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum Wallet)
6. Start ethereum wallet and check the binaries\Geth\unpacked directory to be sure it has downloaded the latest geth (sometimes it gets stuck on an older version)

At this point you should be fully synced (or close to it).