# Does fast sync download all past event logs?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, synchronization, events, fast-sync

If I do a fast sync when connecting to Ethereum the first time, will all past Events (written into smart contracts) be downloaded along with the block headers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Geth's "fast" sync, and why is it faster?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/what-is-geths-fast-sync-and-why-is-it-faster)

Comment: Past answers haven't mentioned Events

Comment: The answer (and PR) states that the blocks and transaction receipts (and nothing else) are downloaded. So it answered, indirectly. It is my understanding that transaction receipts contain events so the answer, in that case, is yes. If you edit your question to ask whether transaction receipts contain events, I don't think that would be a duplicate question.

Comment: @lungj That's not fair. The 'duplicate' flagging is about duplicate questions, not about duplicate answer. It's irrelevant that the answer to this question happens to be contained in the answer to a completely different question. That question has a completely different goal from this one. We want people on Google to find answers to questions easily without having to read completely different Q&A's.

Comment: @JesseBusman I personally don't see how the question as originally posed is materially different." What is X?" vs. what "What does X do?" when X relates to the action of X sounds the same to me. E.g., "What is an actor?" vs. "What does an actor do?" But I guess it's just me. In any case, if the answers to both are the same, doesn't it make sense to close the question as duplicate so contributors can add to the original question? There's a delete question feature for questions that are entirely redundant.

Comment: The SE meta says that duplicate questions can be used to help people find questions phrased in different ways. Also, I did suggest a modification to the original question to make it (in my opinion) different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I added tags contract design and solidity because emitting events correctly is crucial for clients that depend on event logs to sync up with the contract state.

Yes, event emissions will arrive as expected.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes. I am about to resync again because my archival node is running out of SSD space. And I use events for queries, such as select all token transfers that happen from block 1 until block 1000.