# Geth fast mode stuck on syning states after 3 days

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync

i have started fast sync and its was took 3 days
on first day every blocks was synced but its syncing states and now its really slow!

here is syncing result:

```
{
  "currentBlock": 10735343,
  "highestBlock": 10735450,
  "knownStates": 584833661,
  "pulledStates": 584754308,
  "startingBlock": 10734477
}
```

here is console result:

```
INFO [08-26|12:13:23.330] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=6.877ms     processed=584758628 pending=77408  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:13:27.602] Imported new state entries               count=636  elapsed=7.330ms     processed=584759264 pending=77425  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:13:32.088] Imported new block headers               count=2    elapsed=11.847ms    number=10735455 hash="71d3b7…0e55db"
INFO [08-26|12:13:32.300] Downloader queue stats                   receiptTasks=0 blockTasks=0 itemSize=193.43KiB throttle=339
INFO [08-26|12:13:33.786] Imported new state entries               count=680  elapsed=7.854ms     processed=584759944 pending=77018  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:13:40.582] Imported new state entries               count=618  elapsed=10.019ms    processed=584760562 pending=76876  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:13:46.097] Imported new state entries               count=768  elapsed=14.378ms    processed=584761330 pending=76011  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:13:52.082] Imported new state entries               count=588  elapsed=10.860ms    processed=584761918 pending=75758  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:13:54.640] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=7.061ms     processed=584762302 pending=75829  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:00.586] Imported new state entries               count=620  elapsed=10.992ms    processed=584762922 pending=75610  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:04.091] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=5.460ms     processed=584763306 pending=75509  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:05.281] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=10.060ms    number=10735456 hash="261277…ec1ae9"
INFO [08-26|12:14:05.316] Downloader queue stats                   receiptTasks=0 blockTasks=0 itemSize=195.86KiB throttle=335
INFO [08-26|12:14:09.136] Imported new state entries               count=638  elapsed=6.682ms     processed=584763944 pending=75456  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:09.166] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=11.364ms    number=10735457 hash="6cd8bc…d18c5a"
INFO [08-26|12:14:11.997] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=1.012ms     processed=584764328 pending=76285  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:17.521] Imported new state entries               count=768  elapsed=2.411ms     processed=584765096 pending=77453  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:20.346] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=1.352ms     processed=584765480 pending=78070  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:22.298] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=12.015ms    number=10735458 hash="c50745…4caf1a"
INFO [08-26|12:14:22.325] Downloader queue stats                   receiptTasks=0 blockTasks=0 itemSize=179.93KiB throttle=365
INFO [08-26|12:14:23.382] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=1.053ms     processed=584765864 pending=78578  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:26.121] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=1.387ms     processed=584766248 pending=79245  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:29.057] Imported new state entries               count=395  elapsed=1.074ms     processed=584766643 pending=79953  retry=4   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:32.295] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=1.125ms     processed=584767027 pending=80679  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:32.435] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=12.931ms    number=10735459 hash="7d63b2…ff65b6"
INFO [08-26|12:14:33.331] Downloader queue stats                   receiptTasks=0 blockTasks=0 itemSize=187.34KiB throttle=350
INFO [08-26|12:14:35.170] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=1.509ms     processed=584767411 pending=81137  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:37.587] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed="939.928µs" processed=584767795 pending=82376  retry=2   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:42.914] Imported new state entries               count=768  elapsed=5.270ms     processed=584768563 pending=83624  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:45.925] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=1.518ms     processed=584768947 pending=84116  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:48.339] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=1.183ms     processed=584769331 pending=85239  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:51.306] Imported new state entries               count=433  elapsed=4.434ms     processed=584769764 pending=85273  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
INFO [08-26|12:14:52.549] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=10.824ms    number=10735460 hash="499459…5ccd22"
INFO [08-26|12:14:52.972] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=10.718ms    number=10735461 hash="c25179…457362"
INFO [08-26|12:14:53.342] Downloader queue stats                   receiptTasks=0 blockTasks=0 itemSize=187.89KiB throttle=349
INFO [08-26|12:14:54.843] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=1.205ms     processed=584770148 pending=85616  retry=0   duplicate=1090 unexpected=4261
```

anyone know how many states exist now?
and what can i do?

Comment: As long as you're using an SSD be patient and it will sync. Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/what-is-geths-fast-sync-and-why-is-it-faster

Comment: yes i used NVMe, thank u
do u know how many states there?