# Will I be able to mine having my whole blockchain imported using the --fast flag? (Geth)

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mining, synchronization

Having the same problem as in this question: [Corruption on data-block while synchronising](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/corruption-on-data-block-while-synchronising) I restarted my synchro on the fresh/empty data directory using the `--fast` flag. According to this answer: [What is Geth's "fast" sync, and why is it faster?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/what-is-geths-fast-sync-and-why-is-it-faster) I am aware that fast synchronisation imports receipts only, not the results.

So my question is: will I be able to mine having my whole blockchain imported using the `--fast` flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Fast sync imports only the chain and the logs up to a certain point (about 1500 blocks below the head of the chain), where it pulls the entire state at that point in time (i.e. at that pivot point you turn into a full node). It then proceeds to import the remaining ~1500 blocks as a full node. So in essence, as long as you don't rewind your chain below that pivot point, you will have the same view of the system as a slow synced full node.