# What is Parity's “warp” sync, and why is it faster than Geth "fast"?

Tags: synchronization, parity, fast-sync, warp-sync

A follow-up of [one of the classic questions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1161/87) on this site:

> One of the answers to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/87) question suggested using Geth's `--fast` flag to help quickly synchronise the block data.

Now, `parity` comes with a `--warp` flag to enable synchronization in 10 minutes.

```
--warp        Enable syncing from the snapshot over the network. (default: false)
```

How does the `--warp` flag work, and how does using it speed up the synchronisation? Are we syncing less data, or are we in some way performing fewer checks on its integrity or source?

Comment: Why now parity warp on Syncing snapshot 3306/3306 and make sync from block #8030000
its very slow sync to last block - highestBlock: 8719236
with my speed 0.20 blk/s need 40 days :(
How to warp to last block ?
I delete database and restart parity, but it always warp to 8030000 :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's difficult to give an answer without just re-hashing the explanation on the [Parity wiki](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Warp-Sync-Snapshot-Format)...

The pertinent part is as follows:

> These snapshots can be used to quickly get a full copy of the state at a given block. Every 30,000 blocks, nodes will take a consensus-critical snapshot of
> that block's state. Any node can fetch these snapshots over the
> network, enabling a fast sync.

The snapshot itself is comprised of 3 parts:

1. **A manifest**, which is basically metadata about the snapshot;
2. **Block chunks**, which contain raw block data about blocks and their transaction receipts;
3. **State chunks**, which contain data about the state at a given block.

Chunks are currently set to 4MB in size.

So how does this actually speed up the sync? What that wiki page doesn't say is that we only sync the snapshots initially. So for each block at intervals of 30,000, we obtain a set of 4MB chunks. Then in the *background* we continue to sync the remaining block data.

This is equivalent to Geth's `--fast` sync, which first syncs the block headers, and then in the background syncs the rest of the data. It's just that `--warp` is syncing even less data on the first pass, and filling in the bigger gaps later on.

**Edit:**

See also the relevant official Ethcore [blog post](https://www.parity.io/blog/announcing-parity-1-4/), specifically the section entitled Core Strength.