# Windows Parity syncing very slowly

Tags: synchronization, parity

I installed Parity for Windows recently with the latest version 1.4.3-beta.

The syncing was going fast to start but now on 2,400,000 blocks is goes extremely slow to the point of doing only a few blocks a second.

Homestead button is green, but peers is listed as 0/25/25.

I have seen some posts saying to run with --warp, but also seen others saying that option is deprecated. The way I am running is just by double clicking the icon on my desktop (Windows).

What is the reason the sync is going so slowly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's so slow is due to the DoS attacks last fall. Check [this question for more details](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9883/87).

However, this should not happen [if you synchronize in `--warp` mode](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9991/87). To do that, you have to restart your node with `parity.exe --warp`, i.e., by creating a bat-file or a shortcut with that parameter.

And finally, there seems to be an issue with the Windows installer. Version 1.4.3 is not supported anymore. Try to [update to the latest version 1.5.12 (stable) or 1.6.5 (beta)](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases).

*Disclosure, I work for Parity.*